# AppleScript: How to extract numbers from a string?

Tags: applescript

I am writing a script to go to the NYT website on Corona, get the US data, extract numbers (total, death), and to send me a notification. I am close, but when I extract numbers and display them, they are put together (ie 700021 instead of 7000,21). My question is:

How do I extract the numbers so that they are delineated?

Here is the code:

```
set theURL to "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/coronavirus-maps.html?action=click&pgtype=Article&state=default&module=styln-coronavirus&variant=show&region=TOP_BANNER&context=storyline_menu"

tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists (UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell

to getInputByClass(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerText;" in document 1
    end tell
    return input
end getInputByClass

set myVar to getInputByClass("g-body ", 5)

on returnNumbersInString(inputString)
    set s to quoted form of inputString
    do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s
    set dx to the result
    set numlist to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of words in dx
        set this_item to word i of dx
        try
            set this_item to this_item as number
            set the end of numlist to this_item
        end try
    end repeat
    return numlist
end returnNumbersInString

set theNums to returnNumbersInString(myVar) as text

display notification "COVID-19 UPDATE" subtitle theNums sound name "glass"

tell application "Safari"
    close its front window
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your other question I helped you with, the *target data* is already in a *table* and as such I'd use the *table data* to get the information as its structure layout is not likely to change where target `'g-body '` of `5` may not always be the United States.

I get my *data* a little different way:

```
set theURL to "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/coronavirus-maps.html?action=click&pgtype=Article&state=default&module=styln-coronavirus&variant=show&region=TOP_BANNER&context=storyline_menu"

tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists ¬
        (UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            application process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to set CountriesTable to ¬
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('svelte-f9sygj')[0].innerText;"

tell application "Safari" to close its front window

set awkCommand to ¬
    "awk '/United States/{print $3,\"Cases &\",$4,\"Deaths\"}'"

set notificationMessage to ¬
    do shell script awkCommand & "<<<" & CountriesTable's quoted form

display notification notificationMessage subtitle "US COVID-19 UPDATE" sound name "glass"
```

- **NOTE:**  The *code* used to determine when the *page* in **Safari** has finished loading works in **macOS Mojave** and later, however, for **macOS High Sierra** and some earlier versions, add the *words* `buttons of` in front of `UI elements ...` in the `repeat until exists ¬ ...` *code*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Damnit.. i like yours better. Learning coding/scripting at mid-30s as a way to entertain myself on slow 12-hour shifts is difficult. You are very talented! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a list of numbers from the `returnNumbersInString` handler, but just coercing the list to text doesn't normally provide any kind of formatting.  One solution would be to use `text item delimiters` to specify the text to use when joining the list items.  For example, when converting to text for the notification you could do something like:

```
set tempTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set theNums to returnNumbersInString(myVar) as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID
```